# Get error when check whether the window exists in Opencv + Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm using opencv3.4.3 and Qt5.11.3,
I need to check any Opencv window is exist or not and then, close it.

this is my code:

```
        if (getWindowProperty("mywindow", WND_PROP_VISIBLE) != -1)
        destroyWindow("mywindow");
```

when does not exist any window, i get this error:

> OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:
>   OpenCV(3.4.3) Error: Null pointer (NULL guiReceiver (please create a window)) in cvGetPropVisible_QT, file C:\OpenCV_Source\opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src\window_QT.cpp, line 143

and this is Opencv comment about "WND_PROP_VISIBLE" flag:

> WND_PROP_VISIBLE      = 4  //!< checks whether the window exists and is visible

According to this description, OpenCV checks the existence of the window, so how can it be generated error if it is closed?

Is there any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the null if the window name is not correct.not if window with this name is not available.

```
CV_IMPL double cvGetWindowProperty(const char* name, int prop_id)
{
   if (!name)
      return -1;
...
}
```

I solved my problem with code:

```
int tmp;
tmp = waitKey(100);
if(tmp!=-1)
   destroyWindow("mywindow");
```